# How to specify argument attributes in CFscript? (CF9)

Tags: coldfusion

In CF9 doc: [Defining components and functions in CFScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSE99A664D-44E3-44d1-92A0-5FDF8D82B55C.html#WSf01dbd23413dda0e-66bfe46b1200fb22099-7ffc), it says:

```
/** 
*Comment text, treated as a hint. 
*Set metadata, including, optionally, attributes, in the last entries 
*in the comment block, as follows: 
*@metadataName metadataValue 
... 
*/ 
access returnType function functionName(arg1Type arg1Name="defaultValue1" 
arg1Attribute="attributeValue...,arg2Type 
arg2Name="defaultValue2" arg2Attribute="attributeValue...,...) 
functionAttributeName="attributeValue" ... { 
body contents 
}
```

How do you specify `arg1Attribute`? I tried this:

```
public void function setFirstname(string firstname="" displayName="first name"){}
```

but it does NOT work.

Also, how do you translate this to script-style?

```
<cffunction name="setPerson">
  <cfargument name="person" type="com.Person"/>
</cffunction>
```

I tried:

```
function setPerson(com.Person person){}
```

and it does NOT work either.  "You cannot use a variable reference with "." operators in this context" it says.

Comment: if this is a bug, pls vote: http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=80394

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed in CF9 Update 1

```
/** This is setPerson function hint
*  @person this is person argument hint
*/
function setPerson(com.Person person){}
```

This will work, but CFBuilder (as of 1.0 release) will consider this invalid still.

Comment: Do you get code assistance doing it this way? AKA Intellisense

Comment: CFBuilder 1.0 will not even do syntax highlighting once you use dot for argument type... let alone intellisense

Answer (score 6):

Turns out this is a documentation bug. There is no way to provide metadata for an argument in a script block. You can do the hint, required, type, and defaults, but nothing else. I'm asking about the com.Person thing. Mark Mandel suggested importing com and just using Person.

Comment: Thx. I tried importing and using Person, but that does not work either 'cause the function will still assume the argument type is Person in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and found you can do Java style import for multiple COM with a *.

```
import Path.To.Your.CFC.*;
```

I was able to use the plain ArgType then.  You might want to make sure that "Component cache" is disabled in your CF Admin or restart your server cause I am pretty sure CF will remember not finding it.

<strike>The import even "survived" 3 level of inheritance and was available in the childcomponent.</strike>