# cfscript component function with object types in arguments and returntypes

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I have a feeling this is a bug in CF9, from looking at this: [How to specify argument attributes in CFscript? (CF9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591716/how-to-specify-argument-attributes-in-cfscript-cf9)

However, if not, I'm writing a cfscript component in CF9 (pure), and attempting to pass an argument as a type of user defined cfc.

```
public function init(required _lbr._core._sharing._access.accessLinkDAO oAccessLinkDAO) returntype="_lbr._core._sharing._access.accessLinkBusiness" {
```

But CF keeps coming back with:

```
You cannot use a variable reference with "." operators in this context
```

is this something broken with CF9 pure?

Comment: That is quite verbose. I would suggest adding `import _lbr._core._sharing._access.*` to the CFC then you can simply use `public accessLinkBusiness function init( required accessLinkDAO oAccessLinkDAO)` Also...what is with all the underscores in the CFC path...man is that hard to read and type.

Comment: Yeah, what's wrong with just com.domain.app.package.MyComponent as notionaly industry standard? And def use imports to abbrev references to it.

Comment: @AdamCameron I had tried it that way before, but was having the same error so switched it up, it appears the docs don't actually have a uniform way of doing it.  Which version of CF were you using.  I think this may be a CF9 bug that's been fixed in one of the patches.

Comment: As to naming convention... I claim inheritance and no real need to change.... :D

Comment: @Jarede - Understood.....that would annoy the piss out of me though.

Comment: @Jarede could be a 9.0 thing. I'm on 9.0.2 (and was on 9.0.1 the week before last, and never had an issue). From the looks of those paths, they're refs to your current package so you don't need to specify them anyhow. Just use the CFC name instead.

Comment: [I've deleted one of my comments above that @Jarede responded to. My advice was incorrect, and is superceded by my answer, below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed this is a bug in CF9.0 (and fixed in one of CF9.0.1 or CF9.0.2; probably 9.0.1).

However the fix is easy. The problem is only with the dotted paths, and as @ScottStroz points out, you don't need them. This works fine:

```
component {
    public accessLinkBusiness function init(required accessLinkDAO oAccessLinkDAO) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

I've moved the return type simply because that's just the normal place for it: it'll work as attribute too (but that syntax is just awful).

If the CFCs you are referencing as return types or argument types aren't in the same dir as the CFC using them, use an import statement, eg in this case:

```
import _lbr._core._sharing._access.*;
```